# Incremental and Decremental of javascript array

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular-material, array-indexing

I'm trying to create simple image modal using angular material. `next()` supposed to be view next image from the array and `prev()` view previous image.

**Problem**
next and prev function not working as expected. If click next() index only increase +1 then stopped. If I click prev() index become -1

app.ts

```
  const imageArray = [
      {
        imageData: [
          'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
          'https://via.placeholder.com/60'
        ],
      },
      {
        imageData: [
          'https://via.placeholder.com/100'
        ],
      },
      {
        imageData: [
          'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
        ],
     }
  ];

  next() {
    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[this.imageIndex + 1];
  }

  prev() {
    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[this.imageIndex - 1];
  }

  processImage() {
    const rawData = this.imageArray;
    this.imageCollection = rawData.flatMap((el: any) => el.imageData);
    this.imageIndex = this.imageCollection.findIndex((x) => x === this.data.selectedImage);
    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[this.imageIndex];
  }
```

app.html

```
<img [src]="currentImage"
     alt="customer document" />

<div (click)="next()">next</div>
<div (click)="prev()">previous</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not actually incrementing/decrementing `this.imageIndex` but merely using its value which initially as per your question was 0.

Change it like so :-

```
  next() {
    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[++this.imageIndex];
  }

  prev() {
    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[--this.imageIndex];
  }
```

Do add the checks when `this.imageIndex` goes out of bounds.

Comment: When I clicked next() second time, index goes 1 to 3. It's skipping index 2

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the `this.imageIndex` after you click.
Try this:

```js
  next() {
    // if is last image, then go to first image
    if(this.imageIndex === this.imageCollection.length - 1) this.imageIndex = 0;
    else this.imageIndex++;

    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[this.imageIndex];
  }

  prev() {
    // if is first image, then go to last image
    if(this.imageIndex === 0) this.imageIndex = this.imageCollection.length - 1;
    else this.imageIndex--;

    this.currentImage = this.imageCollection[this.imageIndex];
  }
```

Comment: When I clicked next() second time, index goes 1 to 3. It's skipping index 2

Comment: @Johnny i suspect that's unrelated to the code solution provided here